# SharpSVN authentication without affecting TortoiseSVN credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, svn, sharpsvn

I'd like to use SharpSVN with a different user of TortoiseSVN.
I'm using VisualSVN as server and I'm connecting to VisualSVN using https. In TortoiseSVN the url is `https://<myserver>`.
Reading around I've found some possible solutions.

`client.Authentication.ForceCredentials(user, password);`

This definitively changes the TortoiseSVN cache but actually it is the only method to authenticate that works for me.

Methods that starts with

`client.Authentication.Clear();`

In this case, when I use the client I receive the error

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://myserver'
>   No provider registered for 'svn.ssl.server' credentials

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code

```
client = new SvnClient();
client.Authentication.ForceCredentials(login, password);
client.Authentication.SslServerTrustHandlers += delegate (object sender, SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs e)
 {
   e.AcceptedFailures = e.Failures;
   e.Save = true;
 };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: @shuraz thanks for your answer. I already try it and the delegate is never called. Also, with ForceCredentials in my case the credential cache is overwritten.